# SAP UI5 (javascript) Example - 'this' keyword confusion

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to understand how a very simple SAP UI5 app works by looking at some example code. The problem comes from understanding the use of the 'this' keyword. In this code, I don't really know which object is calling the function and hence the part where it says "this.nav.to("Detail", context);" is confusing to me. There is an XML file called "Master" that has a button that executes the function, but I'm not sure the object calling the is actually "StandardListItem" as shown by the XML code.

The code for the Master XML file and the code for the javascript controller is shown below:

"Master" XML file:

```
<core:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Master"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" >
    <Page
        title="~MasterPage~" >

        <List
            items="{/SalesOrderCollection}" > <!-- This is needed for context after pressing the element -->
            <StandardListItem
                type="Active"   
                press="handleListItemPress"
                title="{SoId}" /> <!-- The type = "Active" part of the element enables it to be pressed -->

        </List>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

Controller file (Javascript)

```
sap.ui.controller("sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Master", {

    handleListItemPress : function (evt) {
        var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext(); //This refers to the data binding context of the element that is calling the function.  
        this.nav.to("Detail", context); // In this case 'this' refers to whatever object/element called the function. 
    }
});
```

The whole sample code is found here:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/60668332-b85d-3110-3fb7-8133d856d3e5

The doc is found here:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/8022ac87-1f60-3110-5383-fa68a91d7f8b?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&59017145622993

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` refers to the controller (master controller) `sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Master`

You can play around these variables at run time. Put a break point and see what exactly 'this' refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code, the view is of type XML. Hence any event handler gets back to the controller with the context (this) of the controller. Hence in the `handleListItemPress()` function, `this` refers to the controller. However, if you are trying to use a JS view, you will have to specify the context as the second parameter.
Eg:
    `StandardListItem({press:[oController.handleListItemPress(),oController])`

Also as Sunil mentions, you can always put a break point in the function and find out what it refers to.